# Getting Bot Authorization error after publishing code in Azure

Tags: botframework

I have developed the bot in V1.0 and it is working in emulator once we checked the option use V1.0 for authentication tokens in Bot emulator but when I publish the bot to azure we are getting https 405 error.

[image]

Comment: The default bot state service has been deprecated.  https://blog.botframework.com/2017/12/19/bot-state-service-will-soon-retired-march-31st-2018/

Comment: Can you create a v3 bot instead of v1?